# Is there a difference between single/double quoted strings passed to javascript's eval?

Tags: javascript, json, eval, websocket

i have a server message sent via web-sockets. that message is a json (validated) string.
when it gets to the browser i check that it is a string with `typeof(data)` and it tells me that it is, in fact, a string. When finally i do `var some_obj = eval( '(' + data + ')' );`
it gives me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error.

also, before using `eval()`, i `console.log(data)` and it displays correctly, although an `alert(data)` won't show anything on the dialog.

i can't understand what's happening.

i also tried `var myJson = '{ "x": "Hello, World!", "y": [1, 2, 3] }';` and then `var myObj = eval( '(' + myJson + ')' );` and it works, so i really can't understand why mine can't be evaluated (parsed).

the string received via web-sockets is this:

```
received 37 bytes » { "cmd": "setname", "params": "ok" }
```

where `data = { "cmd": "setname", "params": "ok" }` (with quotes i suppose, because of `typeof(data)` being = string).

any tips? thanks

edit1 » with web-sockets, you have to prepend a null char (0 ascii) and append a escape char (255 ascii) to the output string from the server. i assume the client (browser) as it implements web-sockets must deal with this and unwrap the string correctly (as the standard) and as i do in my server. thing is, there might be some escape char left and it doesn't deal with it correctly. but the problem only started when i tried to send json strings to be eval()ed. otherwise they work properly as any other string.

Comment: You have to understand that the quotes at the beginning (and end) are only there for you and the parser to understand where a string begins (and ends). They are not actually part of the string itself.

Comment: Are you **sure** `typeof(data)` is `String`? You don't mention `console.log` ing this. I think you'd get the beaviour you describe if data was an object literal and not in fact a string.

Comment: typeof(d) » string.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. there is actually something funny happening » when i try to copy from the console, the 'd' (string) with some text before, it doesn't copy... » console.log('received '+d.length+' bytes » ' + d); this is the log command and it generates » received 37 bytes » { "cmd": "setname", "params": "ok" } but i have to manually write it here because i'm not able to copy it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no difference between `"` and `'` for quoting strings other than that you can use `"` without escaping it inside a string quoted with `'` and vice-versa. But I don't think that (the title of your question) actually has anything to do with the problem you're having.

Re your edit, if you want to ensure that there are no characters with the value 0 or 255 in the string, you can do that like this:

```
data = data.replace(/[\u0000\u00ff]/g, '');
```

...before passing it to `eval`. And it sounds like you might want to do that, since your thing is saying it's received 37 bytes but the string is only 36 characters long and doesn't use any characters requiring two bytes (or perhaps it just has a space at the end I can't see).

**Off-topic**: It's best not to use `eval` to deserialize JSON. Instead, use a library that handles it directly. Crockford has two different non-`eval` libs on [his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), one (json_parse.js) that uses a recursive-descent parser and another (json_parse_state.js) that uses a state machine. If you really, really want to use `eval` to parse JSON, take a look at his implementation in json2.js, which at least takes a couple of steps to weed out malicious stuff.

**Off-topic 2**: Re

> where `data = { "cmd": "setname", "params": "ok" }` (with quotes i suppose, because of typeof(data) being = string).

We only use quotes to quote string literals in code; there are no quotes around actual string data itself in memory. If I do this:

```
var foo = "bar";
```

...the string that `foo` points to consists entirely of the characters b, a, and r. There are no quotes; the quotes are only there in the code to tell the parser that what follows is a string literal.

Comment: actually i'm not using eval(). i'm using json2.js with JSON.parse() but both give me the same result... i'll try your data.replace() thank you.EDIT » i did d = d.replace(/[\u0000-\u00ff]/g, ''); but now d is empty (0 length) but still typeof(d) = string

Comment: @mwm: I'm afraid you saw an interim version where I'd typed `-` where I shouldn't have. The correct regex is (now) shown above (just delete the `-`). :-) V. embarrassing, I kind of hoped I'd caught it before anyone saw it, but apparently not.

Comment: well i should learn some regex too. thank you. that actually worked! which means that i was right, supposing some web-sockets implementation chars were conflicting. i thought the browser unwraped the string correctly. thank you very much @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @mwm: No worries, glad that did it. Are you quite sure that this 0 and 255 thing is really required by the web sockets stuff? I'm not seeing it: http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#dom-websocket-send It would be pretty retrograde to require doing that. If you're explicitly doing that, I can recommend trying *not* doing it and seeing if things still work? I have this suspicion you're doing work that the underlying implementation is supposed to do (and is probably doing, duplicating your efforts).

Comment: well, i read that here » The data is minimally framed with just two bytes. Each frame starts with a 0x00 byte, ends with a 0xFF byte, and contains UTF-8 data in between. « http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets#WebSocket_Protocol_Handshake

Comment: @mwm: Right. **You** don't do that, though, your web socket server and client layers do it. Again, if you're manually doing that, I recommend stopping doing it and seeing whether that works.

Comment: but the web-socket server was implemented by my self in php so, when sending data, i use chr(0).$msg.chr(255). if i don't the browser will ignore it

Comment: @mwm: Ah. I have a suspicion there's a missing link or duplication here somewhere, but you're closer to the problem. Good luck with it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder » for sure there is because at the first received message, the first character is null so "[null]{....}" and the second and next messages received don't have this problem they look like ".....}". i'll try to investigate. thank you very much ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you! Your answer helped a lot. I too had a '\0' at the end of a JSON string sent over a websocket. Note to C++ coders: don't use std::ends to end your std::ostringstream!